# Mapping/digging into an array that is nested in an object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mapping

This is my first question on stack overflow. I am attempting to map an array that is housed within an object. My question is more regarding the targeting than the actual mapping process itself (I think). The goal of my code is to map an array to this target:

```js
var target = {
                        "id": 1, //as an int
                        "type": "donut",
                        "name": "Cake",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters": "all of the batter types as a string",
                        "ingredients": [],//a copy of all the toppings
                        "countOfFillings": 0 
    }
```

the object in question is:

```js
var bakery = {
    "items":
        {
            "item":
                [
                    {
                        "id": "0001",
                        "type": "donut",
                        "name": "Cake",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0002",
                        "type": "donut",
                        "name": "Raised",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ]
                    },
        
                    {
                        "id": "0003",
                        "type": "donut",
                        "name": "Old Fashioned",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0004",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "name": "Bar",
                        "ppu": 0.75,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ],
                        "fillings":
                            {
                                "filling":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "7001", "name": "None", "addcost": 0 },
                                        { "id": "7002", "name": "Custard", "addcost": 0.25 },
                                        { "id": "7003", "name": "Whipped Cream", "addcost": 0.25 }
                                    ]
                            }
                    },

                    {
                        "id": "0005",
                        "type": "twist",
                        "name": "Twist",
                        "ppu": 0.65,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                            ]
                    },

                    {
                        "id": "0006",
                        "type": "filled",
                        "name": "Filled",
                        "ppu": 0.75,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ],
                        "fillings":
                            {
                                "filling":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "7002", "name": "Custard", "addcost": 0 },
                                        { "id": "7003", "name": "Whipped Cream", "addcost": 0 },
                                        { "id": "7004", "name": "Strawberry Jelly", "addcost": 0 },
                                        { "id": "7005", "name": "Rasberry Jelly", "addcost": 0 }
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
                ]
        }
}
```

And this is my attempt at mapping. I'm able to get the array generated but only from the first item in the array as indicated with the [0]. Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated!

```js
    var exampleTest = bakery.items.item.map(mapCake);
    function mapCake (aCake)
    {
        let newType = `${bakery.items.item[1].type}` 
         
        let result = {id: `${bakery.items.item[0].id}`,
                    type: newType,
                    name: `${bakery.items.item[0].name}`,
                    ppu: `${bakery.items.item[0].ppu}`,
                    batters: [`${bakery.items.item[0].batters.batter}`],
                    ingredients: `${bakery.items.item[0].topping}`,
                    countOfFillings: `${bakery.items.item[0].fillings}`.length};

        return  result

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function mapCake(aCake) {
  let newType = `${aCake.type}`;

  let result = {
    id: `${aCake.id}`,
    type: newType,
    name: `${aCake.name}`,
    ppu: `${aCake.ppu}`,
    batters: [`${aCake.batters.batter}`],
    ingredients: `${aCake.topping}`,
    countOfFillings: `${aCake.fillings}`.length
  };

  return result;
}
```

Looks like in your function you're directly indexing a specific bakery item each time.

Your `aCake` parameter wasn't yet being used, at each iteration, `aCake` refers to the current item that is being iterated over - so that's what you want to be populating your result values with.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance. That makes sense. Why have a parameter if you don't use it. Thanks again for your time!